# Redirect www and http to non-www with https using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, web, https

I've got the following written into my .htaccess file which is placed in the directory where my index.html is.

```
RewriteEngine On                              
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off                        
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]                 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URL} [L,R=301]

I want that 
www.example.com       
http://example.com    
and http://www.example.com      

are redirected to 
https://example.com
```

Do I have to exchange REQUEST_URI with example.com or am I doing something else wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You must put an OR in between your rewrite conditions

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Note: You have to test the urls as:

[http://www.example.com](http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=b9d10003-5fd2-5937-9e87-2c17817432b3)

[http://example.com](http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=29cb423f-7f69-5558-9c0a-f948145b07e9)

[https://www.example.com](http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=eb7f19e0-6a3b-5d27-b044-38df993792be)

They will all be redirected to

```
https://example.com
```

Comment: which url is redirected wrong exactly? www.example.com?

Comment: so put http:// at the beginning of it, you won't have any  requests without a protocol

Comment: @WoffeLL you have to put http:// at the beginning of each url that you want to test, because all of the requested urls on your server will definitely have that. Can you make a request without any protocol in any platform? This is a web standart..